# Play an HTML 5 video and stop others

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular2-template

I have a list of videos displayed in the page with HTML5, but what I want is that when I play one, the others should stop/pause.

I'm using Angular 2 TypeScript.

```html
<video controls (click)="toggleVideo()" #videoPlayer>
   <source class="embed-responsive-item" src="{{ video.url }}" type="video/mp4" />
              Browser not supported
 </video>
```

```ts
@ViewChild('videoPlayer') videoplayer: any;

toggleVideo(event: any) {
    this.videoplayer.nativeElement.play();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Query all the videos on the page using the `@ViewChildren` decorator. On click, pause all the videos and play the one which was clicked (as you're already doing).

To query all the videos, create a dummy directive with the selector `'video'`. Then use this directive as an argument to `@ViewChildren` and make sure to read `ElementRef` instead of the directive instance (which would be the default).

```
@ViewChildren(VideoDirective, {read: ElementRef})
public videos: QueryList<ElementRef>
```